# redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR value is not an integer or out of range

Tags: jedis

jedis eval script error

script = "return redis.call('hget', KEYS[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDpeJ.jpg), ARGV[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDpeJ.jpg)) ";
o = binaryJedis.eval(script.getBytes(), "hash1".getBytes(), "item1".getBytes());

redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR value is not an integer or out of range

```
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:131)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:165)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:219)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:309)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getOne(Connection.java:291)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.eval(BinaryJedis.java:3306)
at RedisHashTest.evalMultiBulkWithBinaryJedis(RedisHashTest.java:80)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55942', transport: 'socket'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDUsw.jpg)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

String script = "return redis.call('hget', KEYS[1], ARGV[1])";
        Integer integer = 1;
        Object o = jedis.eval(script.getBytes(), 1, "hash1".getBytes(), "item1".getBytes());

Comment: Please format your code so it is more readable for everyone.